# Linq to find inside Array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the below code . Here i want to find out servicelevelid in lstServiceLevels List which is an array of objects of ServiceLevelDetails where ServiceLevelName is "Basic"

Could anyone please help me to get it ?

```
public class ServiceLevelDetails
{
    public int servicelevelid;
    public string ServiceLevelName;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<ServiceLevelDetails> lstServiceLevels = new List<ServiceLevelDetails>();
        ServiceLevelDetails one = new ServiceLevelDetails();
        one.servicelevelid=1;
        one.ServiceLevelName="Basic";

        ServiceLevelDetails Two = new ServiceLevelDetails();
        Two.servicelevelid = 2;
        Two.ServiceLevelName = "Enhanced";  

        lstServiceLevels.Add(one);
        lstServiceLevels.Add(Two);

        var test = from LevelName in lstServiceLevels 
                   let LevelName= obj as ServiceLevelDetails 
                   where LevelName.ServiceLevelName == "Basic" 
                   select LevelName;
        //getting error in the above code .  
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats wrong with the linq thats in your code? in what way doesnt it work?

Comment: what is the error that you get in the above code?

Comment: I need to use the below code to get the proper result.

  var test = (from LevelName in lstServiceLevels let emp = LevelName as ServiceLevelDetails where emp.ServiceLevelName == "Enhanced" select emp).ToList();
            int servicelevelid = test[0].servicelevelid;

Comment: are you trying to get a `ServiceLevelDetails` object as a result or a `List` of all objects that have the "Basic" name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your scope called `obj`, so it's not clear why this is in your query.

In LINQ query syntax, it sounds like you want this:

```
from serviceLevel in lstServiceLevels 
where serviceLevel.ServiceLevelName == "Basic" 
select serviceLevel;
```

Or in LINQ method syntax:

```
lstServiceLevels.Where(x => x.ServiceLevelName == "Basic");
```

If, as you suggest in the comments, you want the id for a specific name:

```
var id = lstServiceLevels
    .Where(x => x.ServiceLevelName == "Basic")
    .Select(x => x.servicelevelid)
    .Single();
```

Comment: Is the below code correct ?

  var test = (from LevelName in lstServiceLevels let emp = LevelName as ServiceLevelDetails where emp.ServiceLevelName == "Enhanced" select emp).ToList();
            int servicelevelid = test[0].servicelevelid;

Comment: Or the below one 

int test = lstServiceLevels.Where(x => x.ServiceLevelName == "Enhanced").ToList()[0].servicelevelid;

Comment: No.  What are you actually trying to do?  Where is `emp` coming from? The second one is closer. The code I've provided will work (I've added an extra example).

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative with which you don't run into exceptions
when the element cannot be found.

look for the first occurrence of this element:

```
// FirstOrDefault will return null if nothing was found
// but it also will return only the first element!
var id_test = lstServiceLevels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceLevelName == "Basic");

// then you can check for it and take the ID if it was found
// or else assign some other value
int id = id_test != null ? id_test.servicelevelid : 0;
```

it's of course a matter of taste either to use try/catch or null testing :)